# How to get execution time of code in android app

Tags: android, debugging, testing, benchmarking

I am trying to get the execution time for any specified method of android application.

I already try with Hugo, Pury library but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use system.currentTimemillis() anywhere in your source code to see the time taken for execution in your logcat.